# How to download a JAR file to specific folder via sh script

Tags: linux, jar, sh, ubuntu-22.04

Let's suppose I have a Ubuntu-22 machine,
and I need to write a .sh script
that downloads specific JAR files, let's say javax.mail and activation,
and locate them in a specific path: ~/jars/folder.

The script for now looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
DESTINATION_PATH=~/jars/folder
# Download javax.mail and activation jars,
# And locate the jars in DESTINATION_PATH
```

Is there any command for downloading the jars into the folder?

**Edit (Solved):**

Thanks @yvs2014 for the answer,
The script I ran eventually:

```
#!/bin/sh

DESTINATION_PATH=~/jars/folder

URL_JAR_MAIL=https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases/download/JAVAMAIL-1_6_2/javax.mail.jar
URL_JAR_ACTIVATION=https://github.com/javaee/activation/releases/download/JAF-1_2_0/javax.activation.jar

wget -P "$DESTINATION_PATH" "$URL_JAR_MAIL"
wget -P "$DESTINATION_PATH" "$URL_JAR_ACTIVATION"
```

Worked perfectly,
One note for those who are not so experienced with .sh scripts and Linux generally, like me:

If you write the script in Notepad++, for example, in your **Windows** machine,
and then copy it to the Linux machine and try to run-

It may end with an error because of different line endings.
(I solved it by just writing the script in the Linux machine using `nano` command, my script is short and it was enough for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not specific to downloading jars, something like this

```
#!/bin/sh

URL='https://download.oracle.com/java/20/latest/jdk-20_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz'
DESTINATION_PATH="$HOME/jdk"

set -e
mkdir -p "$DESTINATION_PATH"  
wget -P "$DESTINATION_PATH" "$URL"
```

Comment: Thanks! it really worked, only without the `set -e`, what does this command do?

Comment: Stop execution and exit if some command fails. (for example it exits without calling wget if there's no DESTINATION_PATH dir and the script doesn't have permissions to create it). In this couple lined script it's not so necessary, just I got used to set it in scripts.